# Logging state to console gives empty string

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a simple authentication form, for which I have written a block of code which checks if the password in the password field, is the same as the password given in the Confirm password field. Now as you can see in the code below, if this condition is not fulfilled, the "Error" state is updated to "Test" and then it's logged to the console. Problem is, the first time I hit submit, it logs <empty string> to the console. What am I missing here?

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SignUp = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [passwordConf, setPasswordConf] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password != passwordConf) {
      setError("Test");
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const user = userCredential.user;
          console.log(user);
          // navigate("/log-in");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMsg = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode, errorMsg);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Card style={{ width: "20rem" }}>
      <Card.Header>
        <Card.Title className="text-center">Sign up</Card.Title>
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Body>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="email" className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>E-mail address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="pword" className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="pwordConf" className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Confirm your password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              value={passwordConf}
              onChange={(e) => setPasswordConf(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="primary"
            className="w-100"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Create account
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState functions in react are async. It means that your values are not updated immediately.

In order to fix it, you have 2 options:

1. Use a new variable as the current value of the error state and log that variable:

```js
if (password != passwordConf) {
  const newError = "Test";
  setError(newError);
  console.log(newError);
}
```

2. Using useEffect:

```js
if (password != passwordConf) {
  setError("Test");
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(error !== '') {
    console.log(error);
  }
}, [error]);
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `useEffect` unless this is a temporary fix and you just log the error to the console. `useEffect` should not handle state.

Comment: Yes you're right. I just wrote it to show the change of the state.